# android child layout not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a LinearLayout with three RelativeLayout inside. The first two children layouts show. The third one does not show. When I change the children from RelativeLayout to LinearLayouts, the third one still does not show. Any ideas on how to fix this? The one not showing contains the ImageView.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back1" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/fract"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#00a5e5"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nume"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@id/fract"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="58 apple"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/denom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/fract"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="46 orange"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/red_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="11 apple "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/red_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/red_1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="13 oranges "
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/guess" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The RelativeLayouts are aligned horizontally in your LinearLayout so make sure all three width sum will be <= LinearLayout width

Comment: Are you sure that the image is ok or you aren't doing anything in the Java code that would prevent it from showing? It appears to work for me

Comment: @codeMagic This problem exists in the `Graphical Layout` as well. I don't think java codes affect that graphical layout. If it were only when I run the app on a device, then that might indeed be the problem.

Comment: Actually I just now discover that the second image is hiding the third image.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely wouldn't be affected by the Java code. Glad you figured it out

Comment: up vote to everyone for helping. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decide to do it programmatically. I get the width of the device using `context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels`. Then from there I layout my pieces pixels by pixels, so to speak.

Comment: glad you were so diligent and found your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your second Relative Layout's height is

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

try putting:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

--edit - try adding a weight attribute.

```
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:weight=1
>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:weight=1>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: My problem is the the height; it's the width. All the same, I did not nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

`android:layout_centerInParent="true"` remove this from the view, if you want to add a view you can add separately out of the RelativeLayout with this your Layout is already in the center of the parent, For debug purpose set the width of each view to certain level so that you can see. Your two RelativeLayout already took the width of the Linear Layout, so no space left for the third Layout.